# Oracle patching

Tags: oracle

Hi everyone I'm a student and I need a help with Oracle patch's.
My DB 10.2.0.5.0
I don't understand how to check which of CPU and PSU patch's were installed.
When I try to use sql `select * from sys.registry$history;`
I got a null, but opatch says on my DB was installed patch set 4 and interim patch 10155843.

[image: My DB]

Answer (score 1):

Whatever opatch -lsinventory says, that is the correct patchset. sys.registry$history only shows patches that were applied after installation. If it's null, then your installation included the interim patch.

Answer (score 1):

`opatch` gives authoritative answer as far as it goes for the database binaries (i.e. files that are needed to run the engine of the database).

`sys.registry$history` is a history of changes to database dictionary (i.e. to the internal Oracle's stuff in your database files).

In particular, PSU ships with SQL files. SQL files shipped with PSU should be run manually after `opatch apply` as ordained by README and, by Oracle's self-imposed convention, they log themselves in the `sys.registry$history`. This table, as you see, doesn't explicitly contain the current version, just some clues to what the current version could/should be.

Comment: What does number 5 mean in `10.2.0.5.0`?
As I know the last number `0` is PSU patch. <br>
PSU and patch set 4 on my DB it's not the same?

Comment: It's the same.  10.2.0.1.0 was the base version (call it "patch set 0" if you want), so 10.2.0.5.0 means patch set 4. Weird, isn't it? And PSU isn't reflected in this scheme at all in opatch.